# PHP how do display the inputted name of a user

Tags: php, post, display

I'm very new to PHP, if you could help me out that would be great :)
what i am trying to get is a way  to display the inputted text with a echo en $_POST function. Ive read about it, but cant really get it to work. For more clarity here is an example. The person types his name in the box and click the "go" button. It would then display: Welcome (name of the person). Could this be done in one PHP file that would then redirect to index? What i mean is that a button is clicked in welcome.php you will then be redirected to index.php and so on.

Thanks is andvance

Comment: `$_POST function` < Superglobals aren't functions. Btw, what you're asking for is very broad. Have you tried anything before asking?

Answer (score -1):

Variable:

```
<?php
$variable = 'hello world';
echo $variable;
?>
```

you need 2 php files

if you post something it's pretty much the same
You do need to have a html input element with 'name' attribute
php file that holds the html

```
<form method="POST" action="your_php_file.php">
    <input type="text" name='name' value="some value">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

php file that holds the php code basically **(your_php_file.php)** the form from php file 1 post to this one

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['name'];
echo $variable;
?>
```

Comment: They also asked to be redirected. Plus, there should be a check if a field is empty.

Comment: Do i really need to 2 files? Cant i just have it all in welcome.php?

Comment: @Sapotick You can do it in 1 file, sure it's not a problem, just make the action post to that same file